# PHP curl no error or result

Tags: php, curl

When running the URL in browser prodivding the same credentials as in below code it generates an XML. However when running the below code from server I get no error message or any result. 
What am I doing wrong is it a IP-block, code error or?

According to documentation authentication is "basic HTTP/1.0 authentication request".

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
$username="myUsername";
$password="myPassword";
$url="http://domain.com?getFeed.php?id=3";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$file = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $file;
?>
```

Comment: What does `curl_error($ch)` return?

Comment: It returns "Couldn't resolve host"

Comment: You have there a typo... `http://domain.com?`

Comment: Tested from other server. Worked. Read somewhere that it might have been an DNS inssue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error you have is that you use the wrong HTTP authentication method, you use `CURLAUTH_ANYSAFE`, but you write that it should be

> basic HTTP/1.0 authentication request

Thus, set the CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH to,

```
url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

(Or leave it blank since `CURLAUTH_BASIC` is the default)

Comment: After I tested sript on new server I modified the code as per above and it did work.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below code as well , and you will get the correct information about why its failing.

```
curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

let me quote [documentation](http://docs.php.net/curl_exec):

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure.

as you do not set this option, `$file` is either true or false. but you just print it.

```
if ($file) {
    // success
    // get the body
} else {
    // failure
    // check curl_error()
}
```